# Disable textfield in destination view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two view controllers: ViewController1 and ViewController2.
My objective is, when the segue is triggered if a certain condition in ViewController1 is met a textfield in viewController2 to be disabled.

I have setup `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and `prepareForSegue` and everything works fine, but when i put the condition it crash saying that it found an error unwrapping an optional- the textfield.
my ViewController1 is :

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if condition1=true{
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}

override  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if  (segue.identifier=="segue"){
        let destVC:ViewController=segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
        if n==1{
            destVC.myTextField.enabled=false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `prepareForSegue` method `myTextField` of `ViewController2` is not initialized yet, so thats why you are getting an error `unwrapping an optional textField`, To solve your crash create one `Bool` instance inside your `ViewController2` and pass its value in `prepareForSegue` method.

```
override  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
     if  (segue.identifier=="segue"){
          let destVC:ViewController=segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
          if n==1{
              destVC.isEnabled=false
          }
     }
}
```

Create instance `isEnabled` inside `ViewController2` like this and used it in the `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController2`

```
var isEnabled: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTextField.enabled = self.isEnabled
}
```

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding :)

Comment: One more question, what happens if i want the isEnabled value to stay false until the n value is changed? I mean if i go to a different viewController or i shut the app down it reverts back to the original.. Should i store the value in nsuserdefaults?

Comment: Yes if you want the value after the app terminate you nee to use nsuserdefault.

Answer (score 0):

The views associated with the destination controller are not yet loaded/instantiated at that point.

Create an instance boolean flag on the destination VC and set that in the prepare segue function.  Then in viewDidLoad or later in the destination VC check for that switch and disable the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can set condition at your destination view controller then you can do this

```
myTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Enable and disable userInteractionEnabled of your textfield.